# download web page source code on iphone

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I need to download a particular webpage on my iphone. 
It redirects me if i use a desktop.
Any tools out there that could help me to do this?
I have tried sitesucker but it didnt work.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question appropriate for this site.

Comment: um anywhere else i cant ask this?

Comment: Try [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it redirects you when you use a desktop to access it, you can right click the link and download page as source. But since you want to do it on the iPhone, you can do the following:

```
// Download webpage
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://yourURL.here"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

And you can access the data through your simulator folder or you directly get the NSString.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://yourURL.here"];
NSString *source = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]
```

Comment: And yes this might not be the appropriate site to ask this question but the code is here to help you :-)

Comment: But it's not a coding question, it's a "user" question.

Comment: @Schemetrical where would i run this iphone code at?

Comment: -viewDidLoad? anywhere where the code can be run. Just beware that its synchronous. And as @rmaddy said, this isn't strictly a coding question so ask it somewhere else next time.